# Is Minimax Linkage a Lance-Williams hierarchical clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms

I found the following article on ["Hierarchical Clustering With Prototypes
via Minimax Linkage"](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jbien/jasa2011minimax.pdf).

It is stated in Property 6 that

> Minimax linkage cannot be written using [Lance–Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method) updates.

A succinct proof using a counter-example is given:

> Proof. 
>   Figure 9 shows a simple one-dimensional example that could not
>   arise if minimax linkage followed Lance– Williams updates. The upper
>   and lower panels show two configurations of points for which the
>   right side of (4) is identical but the left side differs; in
>   particular, $d(G_1 \cup G_2,H) = 9$ for the upper panel, whereas
>   $d(G_1 \cup G_2,H) = 8$ for the lower panel.

But I do not understand their proof. For both cases (upper and lower panels), $d(G_1,H) = 16$, $d(G_2,H) = 7$, $d(G_1,G_2) = 5$.

I cannot see any reason that $\alpha(G_2)$ in the first case must equal $\alpha(G_2)$ in the second case. For instance, $G_2$ has not the same cardinal.

Comment: I also don't quite follow why $\alpha(G_2)$ can't be different... so I'm not sure if that make sense but if you would add another point in $G_2$ after the first one for the upper panel, the numbers wouldn't change but now $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same cluster size and therefore $\alpha(G_2)$ must be the same in both cases!?!

Comment: Indeed their argument seems to hinge on $\alpha$ being the same in both cases. Thenis that the left-hand side does change (from 9 to 8) but not the RHS.   Did you check Lance-Williams article for the definition of $\alpha$ and its dependence on $G_2$? I'll try to see and come back. Your values, though, are correct. Assuming $\alpha$ doesn't chance those values show that Lance-Wallis relation doesn't hold for their example.

Answer (score 1):

*My take after a quick read of the references.*

First of all, [Lance and Williams's original paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-General-Theory-of-Classificatory-Sorting-1.-Lance-Williams/3471d0771c9196415532e0497d981f77aacbf070) mentions that their linear scheme **works (and offers computational advantage) only for *combinatorial* strategies**. Is minimax linkage such a *combinatorial strategy*? In other words, does it depend (linearly) on pair-wise distances? By the defintion of minimax distance it is clear that this is implausible.

It is like the difference between `mean` and `median` computation in statistics. **Mean is linear while Median is non-linear.** There is no linear combination that can compute `median` from `mean` (although in certain **limited cases** they **can coincide**).

Second, [the authors](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ejbien/jasa2011minimax.pdf) do not mention the form (or values) of the $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ parameters in a hypothetical Lance-Williams method for minimax linkage. But in any case they are constants and $\alpha(\cdot)$ can be constant or rational functions of the respective cluster sizes (per the original Lance-Williams reference).

$G_2$ might not be of the same cardinality in the two panels, but minimax linkage distance **depends on radius of cluster not cardinality** (unlike average or centroid linkage) and the two examples have same radius thus $\alpha(G_2)$ is same in both cases.

Another way to see that this is the case is a plausible variation of the proof where $G_2$ in both cases has **both same radius and same cardinality but different configuration**.

[image]

Maybe such a proof would make it more clear. But I will leave it at that, at this point.